# Swift Post request hud,loader is not stop after get a response

Tags: swift, http-post, loader, hud

In Swift i am using post method as a multipart image upload, The Problem is in post method when i get response then i want to stop loader but its not happen i means to say loader is not stop , I am using `BProgressHUD` else every where is working fine. Here is my code . After get a image i am calling image upload method

```
  func ImageUploadRequest_Profile()
{


    BProgressHUD.showLoadingViewWithMessage("Loading...")


    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "\(WebServicesUrl.GlobalConstants.ImageUpload)");

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    let param = [
        "user_id"  : delegate.appd_userid,
        "at"    : "0",
        "profile_image"    : "Test"
    ]

    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


    compressImage()
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img_profilePhoto.image!)
    if(imageData==nil)  { return; }

    request.HTTPBody = createBodyWithParameters(param, filePathKey: "fileToUpload", imageDataKey: imageData!, boundary: boundary)





    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        // You can print out response object
        // print("******* response = \(response)")

        // Print out reponse body

        BProgressHUD.dismissHUD(0)


    }

    task.resume()

}
```

This is get image from gallery method

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage


        img_profilePhoto.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        img_profilePhoto.image = chosenImage

        ImageUploadRequest_Profile()
```

Please help me .

Comment: is it printing any error?

Comment: Try to provide the static value for dismissHUD method. for i.e. BProgressHUD.dismissHUD(2) and then test it.

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                          BProgressHUD.dismissHUD(0) 
                    }
Try this hope it help.

Comment: Yes dispatch_async is working But why this happend